# Is -5 an integer literal?

Tags: c++, literals

Is `-5` an integer literal? Or is `5` a literal, and `-5` is an expression with unary minus taking a literal as an argument? The question arose when I was wondering how to hardcode smallest signed integer values.

Comment: How about INT_MIN from <climits> for "smallest signed integer"?

Comment: Or, since it's tagged C++, how about `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`?

Comment: I looked in climits. #define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1) Interesting :) Thanks

Comment: @Michael: Discard my deleted comment that it is not a literal, since, as I understand, no negative value can be represented by a literal :)

Comment: Why not using (signed)(~0) for minimum integer?

Comment: @Green Code - because it makes assuptions about how the system stores negative integer values, i.e. one's complement or two's complement or other...

Comment: @Armen: Thanks, good point. But i guess 2's is more famous and common.

Comment: @Greeen Code: It most certainly is. No doubt there. But if real portability and pedantic standards-compliance is a priority, that assumption is just not entirely justified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a unary minus followed by 5 as an integer literal. Yes, that makes it somewhat difficult to represent the smallest possible integer in twos complement.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: If types 'long' and 'unsigned long' are 32-bits, would a standards-conforming compiler regard -2147483648 as an unsigned long equal to 2147483648, an error, or Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @supercat: in C++ it's undefined, but then in C++ with the sizes you specify, `2147483648` is undefined (2.13.1/2) - you *must* provide a suffix `2147483648u` or get help from your implementation. You'd hope that the compiler will do you a favour, and treat `2147483648` as an unsigned long, or maybe a `long long` if supported, or an error if all else fails: but it doesn't have to. In C99 (again with those sizes), `-2147483648` is a negative `long long`. I think in C89 it's an `unsigned long`, causing no end of entertainment when migrating from one to the other.

Comment: In C99 with 32-bit `int`, `-2147483648` has type `unsigned int` and its value is 2147483648. There is no reason it would become `long long` because 2147483648 fits in `unsigned int`, and then the unary negation operator is applied to it.

Comment: @R.:  In C99, without the `u` suffix, a decimal integer constant never has an unsigned type (at least that's what the table at 6.4.4.1/5 says; is there somewhere else that says otherwise?)

Comment: @R.: @James McNellis: At least in C89, decimal constants do not become unsigned //unless// there is no signed type large enough to hold them; hexadecimal constants are signed //unless// they fall between the range of the maximum signed value of a certain size and the maximum unsigned value of that size.  @Steve Jessop: In C99, what would be the effect of -9223372036854775808 in the source, if long long is 64 bits?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Hex constants' signed/unsigned behavior is more "interesting" than decimal.  With 16-bit integers, (-1 < 0x7FFF) and (-1 < 0x10000) but (-1 > 0x8000).  There's an annoying gotcha which is present in many languages, though, which is that trying to 'and' a long variable with the complement of an integer type will fail if the msb of the integer is set, regardless of whether the integer is signed or unsigned.  I wonder why modern languages don't fix that (e.g. by using "as-if long" rules).

Comment: @supercat: (1) Um. Good question. 6.4.4.1/6 says, "the integer constant has no type". I don't know what that means, whether it's UB or whether it means the value can be safely converted to an unsigned type using the usual modulus rules. (2) I don't know, in C and C++ I think it's a messy compromise between sane behaviour vs. compatibility, and both lose. Just don't type big numbers, it's not worth the hassle. In "modern" languages, integer literals should probably be as big as you like using some kind of BigInt type, perhaps with a warning if you then coerce them to a fixed-size type.

Comment: ... or do any logical ops with fixed-size types of different sizes. C is a bit too weakly typed, I think. Being able to pass an `int` when a `long` is expected (them being different sizes) isn't too bad, but the usual arithmetic conversions are just *hard*.

Answer (score 3):

As [Jerry Coffin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919311/is-5-an-integer-literal/3919323#3919323), the minus sign is not part of the literal.  As for how to solve your ultimate question,

> I was wondering how to hardcode smallest signed integer values

That's what `INT_MIN` (and the like in `limits.h` or `stdint.h` or wherever) is for.

If you look at how `INT_MIN` is defined, it'll probably look something like `(-2147483647 - 1)` to work around the problem raised by the question.

Comment: Thanks. I already did. Actually I am not running into any problem. I was just wondering :))

Comment: @Armen: Understood. I guess I should say "the problem raised by the question" then.

Comment: Can you tell me what type does `-1` has and what type does `1` has ..? I know this is a basic question but i am having a confusion , regarding this.